# Drupal.behaviors function can't detect Views object when user is Anonymous

Tags: views, ajax, javascript

Goals:
1. have a button in a View that refreshes that View via AJAX on click event.
2. Load refresh script only on pages that have View named "my_view".

I was able to achieve both of the following with the code shown below.

template.php

```
function mytheme_preprocess_views_view(&$variables) {
  $view = &$variables['view'];
  // Make sure it's the correct view
  if ($view->name == 'products_left_in_stock') {  //EDITED
    // add needed javascript
    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'mytheme') . '/js/views-refresh.js');
  }
}
```

viewsrefresh.js

```
(function ($) {
    Drupal.behaviors.myViewsRefresh = {
    attach: function( context , settings) {

        var viewName = 'products_left_in_stock';

        // View is Ajax enabled,
        // and is available as a property of the Drupal object
        // like so...
        var instances = Drupal.views.instances;
        var targetedView;

        // iterate thru the various
        // views instances name to find your views
        $.each( instances , function getInstance( index, element){
                    if(element.settings.view_name == viewName ){
                            targetedView = '.view-dom-id-' + element.settings.view_dom_id;
                    }
        });

        // Define your button click here...
        $('.viewsrefreshbtn').click( function(){
                if(typeof targetedView !== 'undefined'){
                    $(targetedView).trigger('RefreshView'); 
                    console.log ('Clicked refresh btn on view. View Refreshed');
                }
                else {console.log ('Can\'t find viewName on this page');}
        });            
    }
}
})(jQuery);
```

refresh button added to Views footer in Global Text

```
<div class="viewsrefreshbtn">refresh</div>
```

**ISSUE IS:** Refresh button works only for logged in users. When Anonymous user clicks Refresh button - following line from viewsrefresh.js executes

```
else {console.log ('Can\'t find viewName on this page');}
```

and nothing else happens.
Targeted View is present on a page and markup generated for that view is exactly the same as for logged in users. Seems like my function can not find the view when user is not logged in.

**QUESTION:** How can I make this function to detect targeted view when the user is not logged in? Am I missing something fundamental?

I understand this is a lengthy question. Greatly appreciate any insight on this if anybody has time to spare. thanks

Comment: Hello. I think that problem is one of two reasons. The first one - due the some reason views ajax is not available for anonymous (very strange, maybe cache). The second one is that your view-dom-id is wrong. Also for me it looks strange that you have different names of view in your preprocess ana behavior. Do you have live example of this problem to let me check?

Comment: Hi Eugene. I modified view_name for example purposes before posting it here and I totally missed that I made the name in preprocess different. Sorry for this confusion. In my local test site the view name is same in preprocess and behavior. Unfortunately I do not have a live example to share with you.  What do you mean by "view-dom-id is wrong" - Here: _targetedView = '.view-dom-id-' + element.settings.view_dom_id;_?

Comment: about caching: I do not cache any pages right now, also in View setting I have "caching:none, block caching: do not cache". Checked all permission on content generated by Views: all accessible for anonymous, still have a problem, so it's not cache or permission issue...

Comment: I mean that view-dom-id can be changed due the some reasons. But it's not simple to check it without live example.

Comment: You can try enable Bypass Access check in your view if it's not critical. Also you can try grant access for all roles you need in access settings manually. If I got things right

Comment: VIEW-DOM-ID: view-dom-id is a dynamic value which changes every time the page is loaded and Drupal.behaviors.myViewsRefresh function is supposed to pick it up (same behavior for all user roles, but I have issue only with anonymous). Also view-dom-id in my case stays the same for that view after refresh button is clicked and view is refreshed. Refresh changes only the content of the view, not the view wrapper.

Comment: @ar7max - "Bypass access check" will disable access check for all Views. It is not desirable for my application. The particular view that I am working on doesn't have any access restrictions now.  I tried granting access to all roles on that view, including anonymous, just like you said. But that doesnt change anything. My script still can't pick up the view for anonymous. So I just removed any access conditions all together, which leaves view access unrestricted. I just can't wrap my head around why I have this issue with anonymous users.

Comment: Also, it is important to mention that all fields displayed in that view do not have any individual access restrictions.

Comment: Eugene & ar7max - thanks for weighing in on this issue.

Comment: @oksana-c, reproduced your solution and it works for me even under anonymouse. R u using block view? Cuz I'm using page. Yep block view shows same error.

Comment: @ar7max i'm using block view

Comment: @oksana-c, for now I can say that as for me Drupal.views.instances returns empty object even under admin user if view is displaying as block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that solution that works for me even under anonym.
**Stars - changes**

```
(function ($) {
    Drupal.behaviors.myViewsRefresh = {
    attach: function( context , settings) {

        **var viewName = 'ajax_test';**

        // View is Ajax enabled,
        // and is available as a property of the Drupal object
        // like so...
        **var instances = settings.views.ajaxViews;**
        var targetedView;

        // iterate thru the various
        // views instances name to find your views
        $.each( instances , function getInstance( index, element){
                    if(**element.view_name** == viewName ){
                            targetedView = '.view-dom-id-' + **element.view_dom_id**;
                    }
        });

        // Define your button click here...
        $('.viewsrefreshbtn').click( function(){
                if(typeof targetedView !== 'undefined'){
                    $(targetedView).trigger('RefreshView'); 
                    console.log ('Clicked refresh btn on view. View Refreshed');
                }
                else {console.log ('Can\'t find viewName on this page');}
        });            
    }
}
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Your solution works wonderful! and I need to spend more time improving my JS :) Thanks for all your help!

Comment: You are welcome, glad to help